# Importing line attribute table to polygon attribute table

Tags: shapefile, qgis-3, attribute-table, intersection, isohyetal

I made some isolines (shapefile: line) and i intersected it with a polygon(purple): i want to attribute to each of the created surface (one selected is in yellow) the value of the corresponding isoline. However this value is contained in the iso-line attribute table and i can't import it in the attribute table of the surfaces of the polygon. I use QGIS 3.3.
Do you please have some suggestions ?
[image: the yellow is one selection that resulted from the intersection between the purple polygon and the iso-lines]

Comment: If you made the contour lines from a raster, you might better go back and use the contour polygons tools from it.  If you can't do that maybe you could run a one sided buffer tool and then spatially join that to the polygons.  Clip to your purple poly after.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the ["Join attributes by location"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#join-attributes-by-location) tool.

For the base layer, use the polygon file and for the join layer use the line feature. Geometry predicate can be intersects and the join type will be one-to-many, since many lines are going to intersect one polygon.

[image]